# Ruby - how to assign multiple variables based on another boolean variable?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to do:

```
the_tag= line[2..5]
rec_id_line = (line[2]=='@')? true : false

new_contents,new_to_close= 
  rec_id_line? open_id_tag(indent,line) : open_tag(indent,the_tag,last_field)
```

Those two methods both return two values (btw I'm refactoring here)

i.e. for the two variables, I either want to call `open_id_tag(2 params)` otherwise `open_tag(3 params)` depending on the true/false rec_id_line value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to put a space between `rec_id_line` and `?`:

```
new_contents, new_to_close = rec_id_line ? open_id_tag(indent, line) : open_tag(indent, the_tag, last_field)
```

Furthermore `line[2]=='@'` probably returns a boolean value so can simplify your second line:

```
rec_id_line = (line[2] == '@')
```

Or combine both lines:

```
new_contents, new_to_close = (line[2] == '@') ? open_id_tag(indent, line) : open_tag(indent, the_tag, last_field)
```